# How do i know data is displayed in 3 horizontal rows in collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have array with 6 objects and I am displaying like below.
What I need is I want to get horizontal row count as 3
How Can I get that with collection view..?

[image]

I am using below code to setting cell in center of the screen

```
class CollectionViewRow {

    var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0

    init(spacing: CGFloat) {
        self.spacing = spacing
    }

    func add(attribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        attributes.append(attribute)
    }

    var rowWidth: CGFloat {
        return attributes.reduce(0, { result, attribute -> CGFloat in
            return result + attribute.frame.width
        }) + CGFloat(attributes.count - 1) * spacing
    }

    func centerLayout(collectionViewWidth: CGFloat) {
        let padding = (collectionViewWidth - rowWidth) / 2
        var offset = padding
        for attribute in attributes {
            attribute.frame.origin.x = offset
            offset += attribute.frame.width + spacing
        }
    }
}

class UICollectionViewCenterLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }

        var rows = [CollectionViewRow]()
        var currentRowY: CGFloat = -1

        for attribute in attributes {
            if currentRowY != attribute.frame.midY {
                currentRowY = attribute.frame.midY
                rows.append(CollectionViewRow(spacing: 10))
            }
            rows.last?.add(attribute: attribute)
        }

        rows.forEach { $0.centerLayout(collectionViewWidth: collectionView?.frame.width ?? 0) }
        return rows.flatMap { $0.attributes }
    }
}
```

Comment: My best guess would be to divide the collectionView height by the cell height. Can I ask what you need this for as there might be another way to do what you need without needing to get this. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you for your comment

Actually I need to set dynamic height for collectionView.
I am getting height with below code but it's not accurate
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)

If I know rows count i will multiply rows count with cell height(40)
So for eg: 3 * 40 = 120
I will set 120 as my collectionView height

Thanks

Comment: With (collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height) this code If i have only 1 object then height coming like 40 , and if i have 2 objects height coming as 40 ,and those 2 objects are in same row like side by side,

But when third objects comes in and fit in 1st row side by side as 1st and 2nd objects I am getting height as 90 not 40

Comment: Erm... if you're subclassing to create your own layout can you not just store a value in there?

Comment: I get that code from github
can you please add how to store value in that sub class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're creating your own layout subclass then you can add a value to it like...

```
class UICollectionViewCenterLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var numberOfRows: Int = 0

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }

        var rows = [CollectionViewRow]()
        var currentRowY: CGFloat = -1

        for attribute in attributes {
            if currentRowY != attribute.frame.midY {
                currentRowY = attribute.frame.midY
                rows.append(CollectionViewRow(spacing: 10))
            }
            rows.last?.add(attribute: attribute)
        }

        rows.forEach { $0.centerLayout(collectionViewWidth: collectionView?.frame.width ?? 0) }

        // add this bit
        self.numberOfRows = rows.count

        return rows.flatMap { $0.attributes }
   }
}
```

Then in your view you can access the layout (or better still store it as a var) and get the `numberOfRows` from it.

```
if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? namesLayout {
      print("numberOfRows===\(layout.numberOfRows)")
      rowsCount = layout.numberOfRows
  }
```

Also... don't call your own layout `UICollectionView...` just call it like `CenterLayout` or `NamesLayout` or something. :D Keeps it shorter.

Comment: let layout = UICollectionViewCenterLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 140, height: 40)
        collVw.collectionViewLayout = layout
print(layout.numberOfRows)
I used above code but  getting rows as 0 always

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside that function. Is it actually running. That way you can see what the value of `rows` is.

Comment: I have checked and even write like below 

        print(UICollectionViewCenterLayout().numberOfRows)

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCenterLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 140, height: 40)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        print(UICollectionViewCenterLayout().numberOfRows)

    }

Comment: This `print(UICollectionViewCenterLayout().numberOfRows)` will create a brand new layout with no items in it. So, yeah, it will print 0. Look at the code in my answer. You need to get the layout out of the `collectionView` like I showed in my answer. Not create a brand new layout with nothing in it.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint in the function `layoutAttributesForElements` and look there. You will see that `rows` has three items in it.

Comment: if let layout = self.collectionView.layout as? UICollectionViewCenterLayout {
    print(layout.numberOfRows)
}

I wrote above code in ViewDidLoad 
it's generating an error "Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'layout'"

Comment: Yes In that layoutAttributesForElements method i am getting count as 3 but in my ViewController I am unable to get that count

Comment: You need to use the code I showed in my answer. But also... you won't be able to do it in `viewDidLoad` you will need to do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or something. Inside `viewDidLoad` the collection view hasn't finished laying out yet.

Comment: Did you put my code into the function `viewDidLayoutSubViews`? What happened then?

Comment: Yes, It's worked
I made some changes according to my requirement
Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Great! Glad it worked! Please remember to accept the answer if it was correct.